# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Songs with IDs (7, 9, 10, 18, 44, 46, 47, 55) (found 4 results, but was looking for 8)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So, I had a friend help me get Omniauth-twitter working. However, now I've got serious issue. In order to get Omniauth working we had to change the primary_key on the users table to :uid instead of :id. Somehow this affected the songs.

E.g. now when I search for songs I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Songs with IDs (7, 9, 10, 18, 44, 46, 47, 55) (found 4 results, but was looking for 8)):
```

Please let me know what code I can provide to help solve this.

users table (schema snippit)

```
create_table "users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                                  null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: ""
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid",                                 null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

Comment: How are you searching for songs? Are you supposed to have all those songs?

Comment: Yes, I'm searching using Tire/elasticsearch. It was working right before we changed the primary keys around. the user_id on Song.last for example is now coming up nil

Comment: If you change the PK on a table, you also have to change and update everything that references that table; this is one reason that you want to have real foreign keys in your database even though Rails foolishly thinks you don't need them. I'm guessing that you now have a database full of dangling user_id references, I hope you have a backup of your database from before this `:uid` change.

Comment: I don't unfortunately :(. There must be a way to link the user_ids up?

Comment: sure, i've updated the original post with the users table from schema.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35204/discussion-between-apane101-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167414/activerecordrecordnotfound-song-ids-not-linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using tire and elasticsearch make sure you update index for elasticsearch so it won't return wrong ids or missing ids of records that you removed. This would be the case to think about how you'll update index in case a song is removed.

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Song FORCE=true
```

in destroy action of a song you could add:

```
 system "rake environment tire:import CLASS=Song FORCE=true"
```

to update songs index.

```
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    system "rake environment tire:import CLASS=Song FORCE=true"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**update after Kevin's comment**

```
Song.tire.index.remove @song #this will remove loaded song from index
```

method destroy now should look like this:

```
  def destroy
    Song.tire.index.remove @song
    @song.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

found the answer in here: https://github.com/karmi/tire
methods `Tire::Index#store` and `Tire::Index#remove`

Comment: this was a nasty bug, and this solution was dead on target.

Comment: If you have more than a few songs, this will be very slow.  This will reindex ALL songs each time you delete any.

Comment: Good point @Kevin, updated my answer. Correct me if I am wrong.